# Android DatabaseException Error when retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to learn how to implement Firebase into an existing project that previously used a SQL db. I have the write code working correctly, but my read is throwing the DatabaseException error below.

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found a conflicting
>   setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined
>   on android.content.ContextWrapper)

I have done a good bit of research and can only find references to this error when writing to the database, not reading from it, so I am very much confused as to what I might have done in my code to cause this error to happen. The method code is below.

```
protected void lastFive() {
    final DatabaseReference gameRef = database.getReference("Games");
    final List<User> gamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    gameRef.orderByChild("Date").limitToLast(5).addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gamesList.clear ();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){
                User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                gamesList.add (user);
                System.out.println(user.getName () + " : " + user.getScore ());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

The line in the method the error appears to be referencing is:

```
User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

I have only been working in Android for a couple months off and on, and Firebase less than half that, so it is possible there is some glaring error in this I simply do not see. FWIW, this method is intended to display the username and score for the last 5 games played on the app. I am a bit concerned what the output will look like, which I know is outside the scope of this question, but I am unable to even work on that until I can read the data. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

User code being added as requested.

```
public class User extends Application {

    //private variable
    private static User globalVar;

    //variables
    String _id;
    String _name;
    int _score;
    String _date;
    String _email;

    // Empty constructor
    public User(){}

    // constructor
    public User(String id, String name, int score, String date){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._score = score;
        this._date = date;
    }

    public User(String id, int score){
        this._id = id;
        this._score = score;
    }

    public User(String id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public User(int score, String date){
        this._score = score;
    }

    // getting ID
    public String getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(String id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting scores
    public int getScore(){ return this._score; }

    // setting scores
    public void setScore(int score){ this._score = score; }

    // getting name
    public String getDate(){
        return this._date;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setDate(String date){
        this._date = date;
    }

    // getting email
    public String getEmail(){
        return this._email;
    }

    // setting email
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this._email = email;
    }

    public static synchronized User getGlobalVar(){
        if(globalVar == null){
            globalVar = new User();
        }
        return globalVar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the source code for the User class.

Comment: Please add model class for user i guess there is some issue there. Are you putting values in fire base DB before retrieving it.

Comment: User code has been added and values are added to FB prior to this code being run. Ideally, I would like it displayed in a pop up window when all is said and done and display a message "No games played" when the DB is empty, but that is once I understand how to retrieve the data successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception posted I can conclude that you don't have the getters/setters for the fields in your `User.class`. Ideally your `User class` should be like:

```
   public class User{
   private String name;

   public String getName(){
   return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
   this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Please verify if you have class structure in this way.

Comment: I added the user class structure to main post. I'm sorry I did not think to do so from the start.

Comment: What is the Application class?? is it Android's Application class?

Comment: I have the User class set as the Application class in order to pass a global variable when I am sending data earlier in the code.

Comment: DON'T DO THAT... THAT IS BIGGEST FLAW... take the things you want in the other class

Comment: You were right, extending on Application was the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad it helped :)